# WordPress $wpdb->insert() not working on Server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which working in localhost but not working on real server.

```
include_once('/home/engforum/public_html/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

$table = $table_prefix . 'users';
$wpdb->insert($table, array(
    'user_login'=>$Fields['Name'], 
    'user_email'=>$Fields['Email'], 
    'user_pass'=>  md5($Fields['Password']), 
    'user_nicename'=>$Fields['Name'], 
    'user_registered'=>$Fields['DateInserted'], 
    'display_name'=>$Fields['Name']
));

$getRegisterID = $wpdb->insert_id;
$my_user = new WP_User($getRegisterID);
$my_user->set_role("subscriber");

// Update User Meta
update_user_meta($getRegisterID, 'rich_editing', 'true');
update_user_meta($getRegisterID, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'true');
update_user_meta($getRegisterID, 'admin_color', 'fresh');
update_user_meta($getRegisterID, 'nickname', $Fields['Name']);
update_user_meta($getRegisterID, 'first_name', $Fields['Name']);
```

i also tried to check error with `exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );` but not helpful. Can anyone please help me to resolve.

**Update:** i tried to debug with

```
// display fileds value
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($Fields);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit();
require_once('/home/engforum/public_html/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
```

but

```
// Not display fileds value
require_once('/home/engforum/public_html/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($Fields);
echo "</pre>";
exit();
    ......
```

Comment: It seems to be path problem. Try to change `include_once` to `require_once`, and check whether file is getting included or not.

Comment: @Rikesh i tried to check with `file_exists()` function but the same the blank page appear on me, and no result found in DB :(

Comment: Try adding "ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 )" and "error_reporting( E_ALL)" on the top of the page to see if there are any errors or warnings. I too believe the hardcoded url in the include_once call might be the cause

Comment: @kjetilh i have set this `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` but can't helpful.

Comment: @webomnizz I see, but E_ALL covers warnings and notices which might have occoured as well.. it's nice to rule it out

Comment: @kjetilh i just tried with yours `E_ALL` but i don't know why i didn't receive any error etc.. and i also checked the file permissions that is fine..

Comment: @webomnizz have you tried hardcoding `var_dump()` statements at various places in the code to see if the page processing stops somewhere? Also might be good to check that the data like the $Fields array is OK

Comment: @kjetilh i tried with `var_dump()` before the include file.. and its display fine, but if i tried to `var_dump()` or `echo` something then i just getting blank page, no echo display or not any array of data..

Comment: @webomnizz Please try placing the error reporting calls `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` above the `include_once` call on top. To me it seems that an error has occoured and it's surpressed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24560/discussion-between-webomnizz-and-kjetilh)

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be global $wpdb, $table_prefix; is resetting your $fields try to change your $fields variable.